# How to remove punctuation from Cyrillic string in R?

Tags: r, string, cyrillic

I've come across a problem when i use `gsub()` for removing punctuation from the string in R.
I need to remove punctuation from the Cyrillic string, but when I use the function, it also removes the letter "ч"!

I receive the string from .txt file, so only that locale that I mention below works.

Here's what I did

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian")

teststring <- 'человек часто! учитывает* черепашечек'
teststring
# [1] "человек часто! учитывает* черепашечек"
clean <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", teststring)
clean
# [1] "еловек асто уитывает ерепашеек"
```

As you can see, it counts 'ч' as a punctuation mark.
How could I work around this issue?

Comment: When setting `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_GB.UTF-8")` it keeps the `ч` in my case.

Comment: Have you tried running the `gsub()` without setting the locale first?

Comment: Also with `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "ru_RU.UTF-8")` it's working.

Comment: If this still does not work use `[!"\#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_‘{|}~]` instead of `[[:punct:]]`.

Comment: @Godrim Yes, it works in that case. But in the main project I get strings from the text file (using `readLines()`) and I can't read it it properly without setting the locale

Comment: @GKi thanks for your ideas, but these locales don't seem to work when I get the string from the .txt file using `readLines()`

Comment: I suggest following @GKi response.

From the `Sys.setlocale` help:
"In R 4.2 on recent Windows the system codepage is 65001 and **one should always use locale names ending with ".UTF-8" (except for "C" and "")**, otherwise Windows may add a different character set."

Comment: I tried creating a .txt file with some copied [sample text](https://r12a.github.io/scripts/tutorial/summaries/cyrillic) and without stating the encoding in `readLines()` or changing `Sys.setlocale`, `gsub()` still works. So I'm not sure how to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Godrim I really appreciate your effort. In my case txts were saved with not-UTF encoding and I guess that caused all the following problems

Answer (score 0):

As it was memtioned in comments, it is better to set locale the *right* way:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "ru_RU.UTF-8")
```

Then if you need to read .txt files using readLines(), make sure the file itself is saved with UTF-8 encoding. In my case that was the problem.
Then when using readLines() add the encoding argument:

```
happy = readLines("./happy.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Then removing punctuation with gsub() works just like it should.